# Exit not minimize a window?

Tags: c, windows

I am trying to exit a window i've third `DestroyWindow()` and `SendMessage()` with WM_CLOSE and `CloseWindow()` the first two don't work and CloseWindow(); only minimizes it!

Example code of what i'm trying to do:

```
int main()
{
    HWND curwind;
    char ccurwind[256];
    HWND newwind;
    HWND wind2;
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("Destroying in 5...\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("Destroying in 4...\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("Destroying in 3...\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("Destroying in 2...\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("Destroying in 1...\n");
    curwind = GetForegroundWindow();
    GetWindowTextA(curwind, ccurwind, 256);
    //DestroyWindow(curwind);
    if (DestroyWindow(curwind) == 0) {
        printf("Failed with error: %s", GetLastError());
    }
    else {
        printf("\nDestroyed %s", ccurwind);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

So basically close the window but not the process 
example scenario:
I open a new tab on google in a new window this program will close that window but not the whole process. Is this possible and if so what function would i use?

Comment: I'm confused. Your program isn't opening a window -- how do you expect it to be able to destroy a window it didn't create?

Comment: I don't want it to close a window it created (as it didn't create one) I want it to close a window of another program eg. My Program closes a Google window

Comment: `DWORD WINAPI GetLastError(void);` does not return a string pointer but an error code.

Comment: After fixing the GetLastError i get error code 5 which to my knowledge is Access Denied how would i fix that?

Comment: the `sleep()` function is depreciated.  Suggest using `nanosleep()` or `usleep()`.  Note the parameter to `sleep()` is in seconds, so `sleep(1000)` will sleep for 16.666 minutes.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: @user3629249 `Sleep()` (note the capitalization) is a Windows API function and has noting to do with `sleep()`.

Comment: `Sleep()` .vs. `sleep()`  a prime example of why names that differ only in capitalization is a very poor programming practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the thread that owns the window is allowed to call `DestroyWindow`. `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0)` is the same as closing the window with the system menu but it ultimately just sends `WM_CLOSE`.

A window can ignore `WM_CLOSE` and there is not much you can do about that.

If the window is in a process with a higher integrity level than you then [UIPI](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vishalsi/2006/11/30/what-is-user-interface-privilege-isolation-uipi-on-vista/) will block your message.

Answer (score 0):

the function: DestroyWindow() should do the job.

From: 'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682(v=vs.85).aspx'

Destroys the specified window. The function sends WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY messages to the window to deactivate it and remove the keyboard focus from it. The function also destroys the window's menu, flushes the thread message queue, destroys timers, removes clipboard ownership, and breaks the clipboard viewer chain (if the window is at the top of the viewer chain).

If the specified window is a parent or owner window, DestroyWindow automatically destroys the associated child or owned windows when it destroys the parent or owner window. The function first destroys child or owned windows, and then it destroys the parent or owner window.

DestroyWindow also destroys modeless dialog boxes created by the CreateDialog function.